# Change the state of Allow Remote Shell Access using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, group-policy

Could you please let me know how to change the state of `Allow Remote Shell Access` using **PowerShell script**.

Open Run (press Windows button + R) -> type “`gpedit.msc`” -> click "Ok".
Go to `Local Computer Policy` -> `Computer Configuration` -> `Administrative Templates` -> `Windows Components`

1. Click `Windows Remote Shell` -> Make sure “`Allow Remote Shell Access`” set to “`Enabled`"

I could get `regedit` but not `gpedit`.

```
Powershell v5.0 - Windows 2016 R2 server
```

I know I can use `get-gpo` to change the status but when I run "`Import-Module GroupPolicy`" I got error:

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'GroupPolicy' was not loaded because 
                no valid module file was found in any module directory.
    At line:1 char:1
    + Import-Module GroupPolicy
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (GroupPolicy:String) 
                                       [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,
                                       Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Comment: @Bill_Stewart ok..

Comment: Your question is now more on-topic for stackoverflow. You can't use the `GroupPolicy` module if it's not installed. Solution: Install it.